# How to stop a thread onClick with a boolean?

Tags: android, splash-screen, thread-sleep

I am trying to find a way to skip a flash screen by clicking on the screen of the activity. This is what I came to and it works. The problem is that after I click and the new activity is called, the boolean false default if runs again and the intent is called twice. What am I doing wrong?

```
RelativeLayout OnClickSkipScreen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.SplashScreenView);
    OnClickSkipScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OnClickSkip = true;
            /*Loading.interrupt();
            Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(SplashScreen);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();*/
        }
    });
    Thread Loading = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!OnClickSkip) {
                try {
                    sleep(2573);
                    Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                    startActivity(SplashScreen);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            } else if (OnClickSkip) {
                try {
                    Intent SplashScreen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
                    startActivity(SplashScreen);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Loading.start();
}
```

Comment: where do you declare `OnClickSkip` ? do you persist its data?

Comment: Right after the activity class: Thread Loading = new Thread(); and
    volatile boolean OnClickSkip = false; How can I make the data persist? You mean to make the boolean true state permanent, right?

Answer (score 1):

use `SharedPreference`. Then think is whenever your class loads up it loads your boolean to its initial status which is `false`. so you will only meet one condition,all the time, which is the condition you are meeting now.

When i say persist, i mean you need to save your `boolean` state so as you can load it up from storage and check,with this your `boolean` will not be dependent on the initial state which is always false

so in your oncreate it could be this

```
 SharedPreference sp = getPreference(0);
 boolean OnClickSkip = sp.getBoolean("onclick",false);
```

now you can continue; if you want to save your boolean state

```
Editor e = sp.edit();
e.putBoolean("onclick",onClickSkip);
e.commit();
```

now continue to your codes